# gson.fromJson not working after updating my app from api 29 to api 31

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I have an app, that saves current status of the app using Gson:

```
gson.toJson(app)
```

And recovers it using gson also:

```
App app = gson.fromJson(json, App.class);
```

It worked perfectly years ago, now I updated my app from Android API 29 to API 31, and it worked perfectly in debug mode, It can load previous serialized app json status saved in API 29 version of the app. The problem is that now, in production, the APK signed with release key, can't recover correctly the json into a App.class. It is corrupted and gives rare exceptions after recovering the App class from the json and trying to load the App class status into memory:

```
ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.l cannot be cast to d5.b
```

That exception is already retraced with retrace.

My app is using Proguard, but it worked perfectly until I updated to API 31. I also tried to adding minify and shrinkresources to debug version of the app, but in debug mode (pressing play in eclipse) it doesn't have problems to read a save App status saved in API 29.

### Update

I discovered that even creating a new save App class status in API 31, the capp can't recover it! It gives the same exception. I even tried adding these Proguard rules updated to 2021, with same result: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Two main questions arise here:

**Question 1:** why can't I reproduce the error in debug mode launching the app with android studio even if I'm also minifying and shrinking in debug?

**Question 2:** What is happening? how to solve it?

Comment: How exactly does your `App` class look like, could you please provide the code?